# PersistGate opens before state loads

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-persist

I have implemented redux with redux-persist.
All works fine except that the PersistGate component at the very beginning of a page load, after a refresh, releases the flow without loading back the state from storage.

As you can see in the picture below I am getting a log that dumps the state from redux store. This log is placed right after PersistGate component. And the state above is after the page has fully loaded.

[image: console log after the gate opens]

My index.js file (has only imports and ReactDOM.render() method):

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CookiesProvider>
          <Router>
            <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
              {console.log('store after gate opens', store.getState())}
              <App />
            </PersistGate>
          </Router>
        </CookiesProvider>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

My store.js file:

```
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import rootReducers from './reducers';
import { persistReducer, persistStore, autoMergeLevel2 } from 'redux-persist';

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
  stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2
}
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducers);  

const store = createStore(persistedReducer, window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__());
export const persistor = persistStore(store);

export default store;
```

Problem for me is that I have a request interceptor which injects that token into a header for authorization. And few requests are made before the store is loaded (since this gate opens prematurely) and that makes my calls fire without tokens.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So eventually I gave up on this and went with a different solution.

Created my own component:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const StoreGate = ({children}) => {
  const [isGateOpen, setIsGateOpen] = useState(false)
  const _persist = useSelector(state => state._persist);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsGateOpen(_persist.rehydrated);

  }, [_persist.rehydrated])

  return ( 
    <>
      {isGateOpen ? children: null}
    </>
  )
}

export default StoreGate
```

Usage:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CookiesProvider>
          <Router>
            <StoreGate>
              <App />
            </StoreGate>
          </Router>
        </CookiesProvider>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

This will lock the render of the content prop until the state is hydrated.